# Python Pandas Groupby NaN should have the same value in the column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, pandas-groupby

The following is a dataframe:

```
  A    B     C
ABC   [0,3] NaN
ABC   NaN   No
XYZ   NaN  Yes
ABC   [2]   [str,'str']
XYZ   [4,6] NaN
PQR   NaN   NaN
PQR   []    NaN
123   1     ["str2"]
PQR   NaN   NaN
```

Now I want to replace NaN values with values that are in same group i.e. ABC 'NaN' in B2 show be replaced with either [0,3] or [2]. Then XYZ 'NaN' value in C5 should be 'Yes' as other XYZ C3 is 'Yes'.
So there should not be any NaN value remaining all NaN replace by values which are existing in same column by the same groupby() member where groupby([CoulmnA]).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line might work:

```
df.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda g: g.ffill().bfill())
```

Update with explanation: it groups column B by values of A, and then fills forward and backward with non-null values found in the group. This will work if you don't care *what values* you want to use to refill if you have >1 options.

Comment: could you please add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

Groupby `A` and then fill your other columns

`df[['C', 'B']] = ndf.sort_values('A').groupby('A').agg({'B': 'ffill', 'C': 'ffill'}).bfill()`

```
     A      B            C
0  ABC  [0,3]           No
1  ABC  [0,3]           No
2  XYZ  [4,6]          Yes
3  ABC    [2]  [str,'str']
4  XYZ  [4,6]          Yes
5  PQR     []          Yes
6  PQR     []          Yes
7  123      1     ["str2"]
8  PQR     []          Yes
```

You have to `ffill` and `bfill` to replace NaN in the next/previous index, see [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: It worked but when a group(created by groupby([A]) ) had all NaN values in Column:B then some random value is assigned. when a group has all NaN in a given column then it should remain NaN(as we do not have reference where to get value from).

Comment: can you add that example to your question